# How can I optimize this series of loops?

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to compare for two matches on two columns between two similarly formatted sheets for a matching row. Once matched, we would sort through each column of the matched rows and replace data from sht3 onto sht2 to add updated info.

I have considered using dictionary objects for the matching but haven't figured it out, you can see that by trying to match two columns between two sheets, this gets very time consuming when there are (possibly tens of) thousands of rows.

Is there an alternative to dictionaries , if not then how would I bets implement them?

I'm not sure if the following function is relevant but thought I'd include the whole picture.

```
Private Sub update_tracking(sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet, refsht As Worksheet)
    Dim excludearr As Variant, termarr() As Variant
    Dim sht2count As Long, i As Long, x As Long
    Dim sht2rng As Range, cell As Range, pool As Range
    'need to find a more efficient way of this
    
    
    ' for sht3sht, i is rows and j is columns
        sht2count = Application.CountA(sht2.Range("A:A"))
        Set sht2rng = sht2.Range("A2:A" & sht2count)
        i = 2
            Do While i <= sht2count
                For Each cell In sht2rng
                    If cell.Value = sht3.Cells(i, 1) And cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = sht3.Cells(i, 3) Then
                    'call update function
                        Update_cells cell, sht3, i
                        sht3.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                        i = i - 1
                        
                    End If

                Next
                
                i = i + 1
            Loop


Function Update_cells(cell As Range, sht3 As Worksheet, i As Long)
    
    Dim excludearr As Variant, j As Long
    j = 1
    
        'Add column max range
        Do While j <= 35
            'Adds exclusion columns
            excludearr = Array(1, 3, 12, 26, 29)
                            
            If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(j, excludearr, 0)) Then
                If sht3.Cells(i, j) <> "" And sht3.Cells(i, j) <> cell.Offset(0, (j - 1)) Then
                    sht3.Cells(i, j).Copy
                    cell.Offset(0, (j - 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                    cell.Offset(0, (j - 1)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            End If

            j = j + 1
        Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Take the values of the four columns into an array, one array for each column: e.g. `arr = sht2rng.Value`. Once you have all the values in an array, all of the VBA looping will be significantly faster. Once a match is found, the array index can to be translated into a Row # on the worksheet, based off of the range you took the array from. For your case, if your range is A2:A#, the row number will be `index+1`

Comment: @Toddleson Great suggestion, thank you! It's about 2400% faster now on these large spreadsheets.